# Azure ADLS Storage Account changing Firewall and Network setting thru ARM or Powershell

Tags: azure-storage, azure-resource-manager, azure-data-lake

In Azure ADLS Storage Account (Gen 2) we want to make a small change to the NETWORK & FIREWALL SETTINGS making an EXCEPTION to enable:-  ALLOW READING OF STORAGE LOGS (As shown in the screenshot below)

[image]

We want to do as part of the ARM Template or thru a Powershell script whenever the Azure ADLS Storage account is provisioned. I am unable to find documentation on this can someone help me with how we can achieve this setting change thru Powershell/Arm Template?

Answer (score 1):

Following is what is needed in your ARM Template to fix that CHECKBOX to allow the logs to be accessed (Firewall and Network setting):-
Basically the highlighted line will check both the boxes:

"networkAcls": {
                    "bypass": "Logging, AzureServices",
                    "virtualNetworkRules": [],
                    "ipRules": [
                        {